# FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app error in flutter web project

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am trying to do create simple web app with using flutter and firebase. I update dependencies and index.html file with proper way. When I try to execute my code I was getting this error. I've try with many projects but still I couldn't figure that out.

Here is my index html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="sportal_web_panel">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <title>sportal_web_panel</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing || reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "xxxxxxx",
      authDomain: "xxxxxx",
      projectId: "xxxxxxx",
      storageBucket: "xxxxxxxx",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      appId: "x"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my basic flutter code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';


void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(App());
}
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire:
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString(),
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MyApp();
        }
        
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem by specifying the argument `initializeApp`.

```dart
final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp(
   options: FirebaseOptions(
       apiKey: "xxxx",
       authDomain: "xxxx",
       projectId: "xxxx",
       storageBucket: "xxx",
       messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
       appId: "xxxx"),
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

To find these options mentioned in the answer above, go to Firebase Console, click Add App > Web --- after creating, then go to > Settings > Your apps Section > select Web App and then select the Config Radio option.